# Have the currently available Bhagavad Gita versions somehow changed over time?

Tags: krishna, bhagavad-gita

I started reading Bhagavad Gita from [Gita Press link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7T0zBCVuV7cUDRJNTJIX01obG8/view) (free) but the first shloka refers to a conversation between Dhritarashtra and Sanjaya. I thought that it should only contain the words of God (i.e., Krishna) which is not the case.

Let me know if I missed understanding the book correctly.

[image]

Comment: Yes in most of the accepted versions of Gita it begins with conversation between Lord Dritarashtra and Lord Sanjaya. Basically Sanjaya describes the scene of the battle and then begins the conversation between Lord Arjuna and Lord Krishna. Yes different translations change the words according to the philosophy they are expounding but the crux is the same through all versions of the Gita. all the best Sir! :)

Comment: the link in the post is broken. update the post if you have a link

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The *Bhagavadgītā* is a conversation between *Arjuna* and *Kṛṣṇa* on the battlefield of *Kurukṣetra*. *Sañjaya* is narrating the details of the battle to *Dhṛtarāṣṭra*. As such, the *Bhagavadgītā* begins with *Dhṛtarāṣṭra* asking about the war ("*dhṛtarāṣṭra uvāca*"), and *Sañjaya* responding, and quoting (chiefly) the words of *Arjuna* and *Kṛṣṇa*, who had a conversation at *Kurukṣetra*. In fact, the entire war is not presented directly in the *Mahābhārata*, the source of the *Bhagavadgītā* (beginning with *Mahābhārata* 6.23), but rather narrated as a "story-within-a-story" between *Dhṛtarāṣṭra*, who is asking about the details of the war (that's why the *Bhagavadgītā* begins with *Dhṛtarāṣṭra* asking about what his sons and the *Pāṇḍava*s did at *Kurukṣetra*).  *Arjuna* is grieving and frightened over the prospects of the war; *Kṛṣṇa* comforts him with spiritual advice that applies as equally to *Arjuna* as it does today to every human. This spiritual advice is known as the *Bhagavadgītā*.

The *Bhagavadgītā* is not changed in any way. The original Sanskrit version was the same version that has always existed. Only the translations vary. **The *Bhagavadgītā* is a conversation on multiple levels (the conversation between *Dhṛtarāṣṭra* and *Sañjaya*, with a "sub-conversation" between *Kṛṣṇa* and *Arjuna* that is the most important part of the *Bhagavadgītā*), not a monologue by *Kṛṣṇa*, and it has not changed.**

**UPDATE:** Upon further examination, I found out that the BORI critical edition of the *Mahābhārata* does not consider *Bhagavadgītā* 13.1 (which would be *Mahābhārata* 6.35.1 if it existed in the critical edition) to be a valid verse. This verse hardly matters, however. It is just *Arjuna* expressing his desire for knowledge.